# Downloading image from server using Android

Tags: android, image, download, server

I am trying to download an image from the internet. Right now the app downloads only part of the image, but then it stops. I am using AsyncTask. Any suggestions on what to do?

The error I get is:

```
android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
 at com.example.reynaldo.getimageserver.MainActivity$DownloadAsyncTask.onPostExecute(MainActivity.java:74)
W/System.err:     at com.example.reynaldo.getimageserver.MainActivity$DownloadAsyncTask.onPostExecute(MainActivity.java:30)
```

This is the code I have:

```
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

public void onClick (View view){
    DownloadAsyncTask task = new DownloadAsyncTask();
    task.execute(new String[] {"http://res.cloudinary.com/demo/image/upload/w_500,f_auto/sample.jpg" });
}

private class DownloadAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {


    Bitmap bitmap = null;
    InputStream in = null;

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls){


        int response = -1;
        URL url;

        try {
            url = new URL("http://res.cloudinary.com/demo/image/upload/w_500,f_auto/sample.jpg");

        URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();

        if (!(conn instanceof HttpURLConnection))
            System.out.println("This is wrong");


        HttpURLConnection httpConn = (HttpURLConnection) conn;
        httpConn.setAllowUserInteraction(false);
        httpConn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
        httpConn.setRequestMethod("GET");
        httpConn.connect();

        response = httpConn.getResponseCode();
        if (response == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
            in = httpConn.getInputStream();
            return "success";
        }
        }

    catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("IOException");
    }
        return "Download failed";
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        //try {
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
         /*   in.close();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }*/
        ImageView img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);

        img.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    }

}
```

}

Comment: One problem is that AsyncTask's onPostExecute() runs on the UI thread, and you can't do networking on the UI thread.  You could decode the bitmap right inside of doInBackground(), and then let onPostExecute() give it to the View.

Comment: Or you could you an image downloader like Picasso

Comment: use picasso or retrofit for image downloader.

Answer (score 0):

**try this if you dont want to use third party library**

```
        new DownloadImage(Imageview).execute(YourUrl);
```

**Create a AsyncTask Class**

```
    public class DownloadImage extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
    CircleImageView bmImage;

    public DownloadImage(ImageView bmImage) {
        this.bmImage = (CircleImageView) bmImage;
    }

    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
        String urldisplay = urls[0];
        Bitmap mIcon11 = null;
        try {
            InputStream in = new java.net.URL(urldisplay).openStream();
            mIcon11 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("Error", e.getStackTrace().toString());

        }
        return mIcon11;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
        bmImage.setImageBitmap(result);
    }
}
```